# How to change content of a website locally after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want not to show price of any product listed on amazon, flipkart, paytm or shopclues. How can i remove that price or set it to zero.

Comment: Please be more precise!! What is exactly you want to do?

Comment: Yes more details will allow us to help you

Comment: I want to buy some products from these sites for some of my family members but i do not want to show them price. As the price is also mentioned for each product so i want it to remove or set it to zero after loading that page. later i will buy those item without telling them the price.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using an extension, for example, [stylebot for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha)
Once installed, go to amazon, open the extension and go to advanced, and add `display:none` for the elements you want to hide, for example:

```
span.a-size-base.a-color-price.acs_product-price__buying {
    display:none    
}
```

(The element class name / id could vary)

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you so much Frankusky.